# How to import multiple files via one symlink in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, environment-variables, pythonpath

I have a script `script.py` and multiple modules in a different directory that all depend on each other. For simplicity, we just look at two of them, `module1.py` and `module2.py`, where the first imports the latter. All these should be used by `script.py`.

Now I added a symlink to `module1.py` into the directory of `script.py`, so my directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── mymodules
│   ├── module1.py
│   └── module2.py
└── myscript
    ├── module1.py -> ../mymodules/module1.py
    └── script.py
```

Just running `script.py` now doesn't work, because `PYTHONPATH` does not contain the `mymodules` directory, and `module1` is therefore unable to import `module2`. Now, there is an easy workaround for this; Appending the path of `module1.py` to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(__file__),os.path.pardir)))
```

And this is where problems emerge: *This works, but only once!*

The first run works fine, all modules are imported without any problems.

But every subsequent execution of `$ ./script.py` fails with the exception `ImportError: no module named module2` and `sys.path` contains the directory of the symlink, not the file! *Why? And how do I fix this?*

---

---

### All of the code:

I thought you could need this if you wanted to try this yourself.

#### myscript/script.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import module1
```

#### mymodules/module1.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys, os

#append directory of this file to PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.realpath(__file__),os.path.pardir))) 

#print for control reasons
print sys.path

import module2
```

#### mymodules/module2.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "import successful!"
```

Comment: it is very critical, to change `sys.path` inside a module. If really needed, only set it in script.py

Comment: @Daniel Could you go into more detail about that? I thought the whole point of python was that you can change everything at any time you want. Why not the `PYTHONPATH`? I mean it's really just an include path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, `append` the real dirname to `sys.path`

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

This output is

```
import successful
```

However, after symbolic `module1.py` is compiled to `module1.pyc`, `modeul1.pyc` will be located at `myscript`. The above code does not work.

## Solution

So solution is to modify `mymodules/module1.py` as

```
import os
import sys

srcfile = __file__
if srcfile.endswith('.pyc'):
    srcfile = srcfile[:-1] # pyc to py
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(srcfile)))

import module2
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I totally forgot about the `.pyc` files, and your solution is pretty versatile. Thanks!